# I wrote a k8s deployment yml sample, but it can not run

Tags: kubernetes

I wrote a k8s deployment yml sample, but it failed every time I apply it to the cluster, the logs is that

> standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

the yml file is as follows, I am new to kubernetes, and stuck here now, wish you could help me

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nub1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nub1
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nub1
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nub1
          image: johnhaha/nub1:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
```

the docker build file is

```
FROM node:lts
ADD index.js /index.js
CMD node index.js
```

Comment: #1 FROM node:lts 
#2 ADD index.js /index.js 
#3 CMD node index.js

Comment: It's just 3 lines, can you see what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec format error` means you're trying to run a binary on a platform other than the one for which it was compiled. Looking at your image, it appears the binaries are built for an ARM platform:

```
$ file bash
bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=29b2624b1e147904a979d91daebc60c27ac08dc6, stripped
```

Your Kubernetes environment is probably an x86_64 environment and won't be able to run your ARM binaries. The `docker buildx` command (see [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/#build-multi-platform-images)) is able to build multi-platform images, so that may be something worth investigating.

---

You need to build a Docker image appropriate for the platform on which you will be running it.

Comment: Ah, I think it's the reason cause I am using an M1 Mac , I will try the way you suggested, thank you so much.